# Python: replace a decimal number in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have strings like this in a number of files:

```
 STEP.M                                   0.02540:STEP LENGTH
```

(notice the space in the first character of the string)
In some of the files, there could be additional spaces between some characters:

```
STEP . M                                   0.02540 : STEP LENGTH
```

How can I replace the decimal number with another decimal number?
i.e. I want this:

```
STEP.M                                   1.50000:STEP LENGTH
```

Edit to add: Naturally, the decimal number is not always the same in each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', '1.50000', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good time for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 =  'STEP.M                                   0.02540:STEP LENGTH'
>>> s2 = 'STEP . M                                   0.02540 : STEP LENGTH'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', '1.50000', s1)
'STEP.M                                   1.50000:STEP LENGTH'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', '1.50000', s2)
'STEP . M                                   1.50000 : STEP LENGTH'
```